# How to get stray kittens to not be afraid of humans?

Tags: cats, behavior, training, fear, strays

There are two kittens that have moved into my backyard. Their body is maybe 8 inches in length and they are able to eat the cat food I put out. They come to my backyard because I put out food and the landscaping offers tons of hiding places.

They run away whenever I am nearby, even if I'm carrying the food bag. Is there some steps I can take to make them not afraid?

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is slowly acclimate them to your presence, start putting out food in a specific place and a specific time, if you haven't already been doing that, and choose a place somewhat nearby but not too close to that spot and sit there when you feed then, slowly move these places closer together until they are comfortable with you being next to them. Now that they are comfortable with you feeding them, start spending more time with them and pretty soon they might let you touch them.

Comment: Welcome to Pets.